# How to force jQuery Ajax to serialize data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, serialization, hmac

**Question:** How do I force jQuery Ajax to serialize the data?

jQuery Ajax **'data'** can be any of the three data types:

> Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>
> Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if
>   not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See
>   processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must
>   be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple
>   values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting
>   (described below).

I believe, when jQuery.ajax "processes"/"serialize"/"urlencode" the data, it merges the parameters set in ajaxSetup. However, it doesn't seem like it does this before it gets to the  **beforeSend** hook.

```
$.ajaxSetup(
    beforeSend: (xhr, settings) ->
         console.log settings.data
)
```

will either spit out something like:

```
timestamp=1404768761739&utf8=%E2%9C%93&_method=put&authenticity_token=EsRpMWMOaQAxJ6XgNJKyh8Yj7WUvkaSkC7n0MmVvjZM%3D&dropdown=true&id=597&name=raise_head&number=0
```

or

```
{"750":{"silent":true},"id":"597","scope":true}
```

it all depends on how ajax is being used in the app, whether it using $.ajax explicitly, or via backbone.js, or hijacking a form submission.

**Question (Again):** How do I force jQuery Ajax to serialize the data?

**Why? / Context:**

The app as a whole needs to sign all requests with HMAC-SHA256.

```
jQuery ->
  $.ajaxSetup(
    data:
      timestamp: +new Date

    statusCode:
      401: (data) ->
        alert( "ERROR #839.0: Access Denied" )
        console.log data.responseText

    beforeSend: (xhr, settings) ->
      xhr.setRequestHeader('x-api-key', SLNAK)

      # Type of request?
      if settings.type == 'GET'

        # At minimum the timestamp param has been set.
        if match = settings.url.match(/\?(.*)/)
          hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(match[1], SLNAS).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
          xhr.setRequestHeader('x-api-hmac', hmac)

        else
          alert('ERROR #839.1: Encryption was not able to calculate.')
          #location.reload();

      else
        # la pôsté
        if settings.data && settings.data.length > 0
          hmac = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(settings.data, SLNAS).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64)
          xhr.setRequestHeader('x-api-hmac', hmac)

        else
          alert('ERROR #839.2: Encryption was not able to calculate.')
          #location.reload();

  )
```

Comment: actually i think you might be seeing it before jQuery transforms and sends() the data, are you seeing those different formats on the actual server?

Answer (score 0):

You could always check if data is object in `beforeSend` and serialize it yourself if it is using **[jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)**

```
if( typeof settings.data === 'object' ){
    settings.data = $.param( settings.data ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the [jQuery.prefilter](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/) function i use (better than doing it in the beforeSend), it will match any datatype, and will serialize any object in a post or put request.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, org) {
    var rtype = options.type.toLowerCase();
    if ((rtype === "post" || rtype === "put") && org.data !== null && typeof org.data === 'object') {
        options.data = JSON.stringify(org.data);
    }
});
```

hope this helps